# MVC helper for a dropdown list that uses a List<Cars>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a List collection in my strongly typed viewdata.

How do I use the Html.DropDownList helper?

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(ViewData.Model.Cars) %>
```

(the above doesn't work, doesn't seem to match any of the signatures)

This is MVC2.

Comment: See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `Car` class looked something like this

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you put a property on your view model like this

```
public int CarId { get; set; }
```

Your resulting view model would look like this

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }

    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

You could do this

```
this.Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CarId, new SelectList(this.Model.Cars, "Id", "Name"))
```

When posted, `CarId` would get get bound to the bound by the default model binder if the view model was a parameter to the `Action`.

Comment: CarId is to pre-select the drop down list?

Comment: @codecompleting Yes. So you set that property on your view model to the id of the car you want to be selected. Additionally, in MVC you can use the default model binder (you have to do nothing for this) to bind form data to your view model. If you were to POST the form to an `Action` which accepted one of your view models as a parameter, the `CarId` property will get set automatically by the default model binder.